# Can I enable lapto mode without laptop-mode-tools

Tags: power-management, battery

I have been reading on the forums that laptop mode is a feature in new Linux kernels that could enhance battery life. I am very frantic about battery on my laptop and I want to make sure I have everything set up properly so that I can increase the battery life as much as possible. So my question is: **Can I enable laptop mode without having laptop-mode-tools installed?** I am asking because I have **tlp + powertop**
 installed and they seem to be doing quite a nice job, and laptop-mode-tools is said to interfere with tlp. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I don't see why you can't uninstall TLP, try laptop-mode-tools and keep what works better for you. In my case TLP is just easier and don't need to configure it that much, that works better for me.

Answer (score 0):

laptop_mode is just one of many powersave features. TLP enables laptop_mode by default. So no need to change anything.

Proof: see the output of tlp-stat (on battery!):

```
+++ File System
/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode = 2
```

Comment: btw: using `powertop --auto-tune` together with TLP doesn't improve anything, see the [TLP FAQ](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#powertop).